# How do I remove all instances called by the AddChild function?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a sniper game and I'm trying to fix a issue I run into when I click the character to kill him. Anyways, long sotry short multiple instances of a MovieClip are created and I need them all to be removed at the same time when a if statement is executed. Is this possible, if so, what is the code?

Code:

```
stop();
Mouse.hide();


var blood:Array = [];

// after you create your clips your needing to keep track of.


var level_complete1:level_complete = new level_complete();
var ammo:Number = 5;
var cash:Number= 100;
var level:Number = 1;
var exp:Number = 0;
var blood_c:Number = 0;
var exp_needed = 25;
var dead_check:Number = 0; //Check to see if the target is dead
var check_blood:Number = 0; //Check to make sure blood doens't loop
var blood_splat1:blood_splat = new blood_splat();
blood.push(blood_splat1);

target1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, target_shot);
function target_shot(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if(dead_check==0){
        addChild(blood_splat1);
        blood_splat1.y = mouseY;
        blood_splat1.x = mouseX;
        target1.gotoAndPlay(32);
        if (blood_splat1.currentFrame==6){
            //blood_splat1.gotoAndStop(6);
            //removeChild(blood_splat1);
            cash=cash+150;
            exp=exp+25;
            ammo=ammo-1;
            dead_check = 1;
            blood_c = 1;

            }
        }
    if (dead_check==1){
        addChild(blood_splat1);
        blood_splat1.y = mouseY;
        blood_splat1.x = mouseX;
        target1.gotoAndStop(38);
        blood_c = 1;
        //if (blood_splat1.currentFrame==6){
            //blood_splat1.gotoAndStop(6);

    if (blood_c==1){
        for each(var mc:MovieClip in blood){
            mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
            blood.splice(blood.indexOf(mc), 1);
}
        }

            }



    }
```

Comment: change var mc:MovieClip in blood to var mc:blood_splat in blood This really shouldn't matter since mc is derived from sprite and your blood_splat has to be either a sprite or mc. I am not seeing an issue with it. well I see a null reference possibility but that isn't your problem right now.

Comment: The blood movieclip still isn't being removed. Any ideas?

Comment: are you 100% sure it is getting to the code. stick a trace("blah"); right before the for each

Comment: For some weird reason it's not.

Comment: I just put your code in flash it looks like your brackets are messed up. right before the if (blood_c == 1) line put a } and then delete one of the ones after that if statement.

Comment: Alright, well I fixed the brackets issues and now the trace statement is running but the nuke code isn't.

Comment: Do you want me to make a video showing you that it's not working?

Comment: hehe no I believe you. updating the code now. we are getting rid of the array since the way your doing this you don't need it. It is just one mc. Your original question sounded like a bunch of mc's.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. Let me know when it's updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: 
Ok here is the problem I see from testing.
Your never getting blood_c set to 1 so it will never remove the blood splat. if you force it (for testing I forced it to = 1) you will never see the blood splat because it is removed instantly after it is created.

So my advice is when you first addChild(blood_splat1); you make a timer. or a frame counter. or something and when it counts down or fires (like a timer it calls a function to remove the blood splat. Like this:

```
stop();
Mouse.hide();


import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var bloodTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1); // one second and doesn't repeat.

//var level_complete1:level_complete = new level_complete();
var ammo:Number = 5;
var cash:Number= 100;
var level:Number = 1;
var exp:Number = 0;
var blood_c:Number = 0;
var exp_needed = 25;
var dead_check:Number = 0; //Check to see if the target is dead
var check_blood:Number = 0; //Check to make sure blood doens't loop
var blood_splat1:blood_splat = new blood_splat();

target1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, target_shot);

function removeBlood(te:TimerEvent):void
{
    if(blood_splat1.parent != null && blood_splat1.parent.contains(blood_splat1))
    {
        blood_splat1.parent.removeChild(blood_splat1);
    }
}

function target_shot(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(dead_check==0)
    {
        addChild(blood_splat1);
        bloodTimer.start();
        bloodTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, removeBlood);
        blood_splat1.y = mouseY;
        blood_splat1.x = mouseX;
        target1.gotoAndPlay(32);
        if (blood_splat1.currentFrame==6)
        {
            //blood_splat1.gotoAndStop(6);
            //removeChild(blood_splat1);
            cash=cash+150;
            exp=exp+25;
            ammo=ammo-1;
            dead_check = 1;
            blood_c = 1;

        }
    }
    if (dead_check==1)
    {
        addChild(blood_splat1);
        bloodTimer.start();
        bloodTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, removeBlood);
        blood_splat1.y = mouseY;
        blood_splat1.x = mouseX;
        target1.gotoAndStop(38);
        blood_c = 1;
        //if (blood_splat1.currentFrame==6){
            //blood_splat1.gotoAndStop(6);}
    }
}
```

Comment: The blood_splat child is being displayed but isn't being deleted. My code is above....

Comment: Alright, it's working but it takes two shots before the blood_splat1 disappears... so what are we doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like it is never getting to blood_c == 1. in the first IF move the blood_splat1.gotoAndStop(6) above the if statement. I don't see how it is ever getting to dead check 1 or blood c 1. something might be out of order there. I think it will run though the loop so fast you will be lucky if it flashes on the screen though

Comment: That's commented out, so it doesn't matter. Or do you want me to uncomment it and move it above the first if statement?

Comment: I now feel your pain. I see what your original probably really looked like. (Have it running in flash now). give me a min hehe.

Comment: Oh thanks for all this help but just one more thing... it seems that it's going through it twice before it disappears,  have any idea why?

Comment: sorry we have ran around the block with this hehe... I don't know why it looks like it is doing it twice for you. That exact code that I posted is what I used to test and it only runs once per click. I put traces in to double check and it is only running once per click for me.

Comment: It's all good... Thanks again for all this help! Your answer was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Down and dirty, you can do this (but it won't remove children of the children) :

```
while (numChildren > 0) {
    removeChild(getChildAt(0));
}
```

Comment: It won't have to, unless you have some weird listeners or something on the children of children the garbage collector will nuke them sooner or later because they would be orphaned.